# AOSP add new custom System Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-source, android-service-binding

I've downloaded the Android Source from source.android.com build it and was able to run it successfully on an emulator.

Now I want to add new System Service to Android. I do not have much idea in building and running AOSP considering this is my first time doing so.

I followed this simple article in adding a TestService to AOSP. Added the new codes, modified SystemServer.java accordingly, but make command wasn't a success.

After the modifications I ran

```
make update-api
```

to update current.txt
After which I ran

```
make -j4 command
```

which failed with the following errors.

```
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java:268: illegal character: \8220
            ServiceManager.addService(“Test”, new TestService(context));
                                      ^
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java:268: ';' expected
            ServiceManager.addService(“Test”, new TestService(context));
                                       ^
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java:268: illegal character: \8221
            ServiceManager.addService(“Test”, new TestService(context));
                                           ^
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java:268: ';' expected
            ServiceManager.addService(“Test”, new TestService(context));
                                            ^
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java:268: ';' expected
            ServiceManager.addService(“Test”, new TestService(context));
                                                                      ^
```

Clearly the errors are on the lines where I added couple of lines to SystemServer.java to register the Service. So how do I deal with compilation errors in the java files that I added/modified? I'm thinking this is something trivial, but don't have enough experience with AOSP get a hold of this. Any thoughts/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are using "funny" quote characters which are apparently illegal in source code.  If I experimentally initiate an edit of your post, and type a normal quote character next to yours, they look different.  Perhaps you have some internationalization setting confusing things?   You could try copying and pasting from working sourcecode.

Comment: Yup I'm using "" quotes. But I checked the code in SystemServer.java (that is the same file I edited) and it has the same quotes being used.

Comment: I suggest you change them, as it is clearly the source of the error.

Comment: Are you able to add new service?..

I followed the steps suggested in [link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService).

But while adding service in SystemServer.java. I am getting PERMISSION_DENIED security exception.

Below is the piece of code throwing that exception.

try {
    Slog.i(TAG, "Test Service");
    ServiceManager.addService(“Test”, new TestService(context));
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Slog.e(TAG, "Failure starting TestService Service", e);
}

Comment: Can we add system service in AOSP without downloading full AOSP code to our machine. Is there any way to write and run system service in IDE and push code in AOSP after fully working and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris pointed out it was due to "funny" quote which got sneaked in.

Comment: Can we add system service in AOSP without downloading full AOSP code to our machine. Is there any way to write and run system service in IDE and push code in AOSP after fully working and tested?

Comment: Unfortunately not